# Is the Welcome to Gmail message from andy-noreply real?

Tags: gmail, email

[image]After making a new account on Gmail we get email from Andy saying Welcome to Gmail. I believe it was not there in earlier version of Gmail. The email address is `andy-noreply@google.com`

[image]

Comment: Can you share the full email?

Comment: It says welcome to gmail

Comment: @arieljannai Updated with image

Answer (score 2):

On [Google Product Forums](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/gmail/PIPKS_r3xf8), a Google employee (Andy B., Gmail Community Manager) recognized this message as real.

Comment: So is it normal ?

Comment: Yes, it seems every new user is getting it now. Similar to how every new Stack Overflow user gets an automatic welcome email.